# Synchronizing timer with bitmap refresh

Tags: c#, timer, camera, synchronization

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217280/timer-first-tick-happening-too-fast?noredirect=1#comment87453046_50217280) I have been told that I would probably have issues regarding the `Timer_Tick` event happening during the `bitmap` change, which would prevent my chart to update. This is, indeed, happening, as my chart seems to update in an erratic way.

Someone suggested that I add some sort of "synchronization" between the `Timer`and the `bitmap`refresh. I read a few things online about synchronization in C#, as I have never used such a thing, but nothing that really related to my concern.

I have not the slightest clue as to how I could implement this kind of behaviour in my code. Is someone able to help me here ? The code related to this question is featured in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217280/timer-first-tick-happening-too-fast?noredirect=1#comment87453046_50217280), in case you want to look at it.

Thanks

EDIT : Here is a more detailled version of the code that starts the acquisition from the camera :

```
private void BtAcquisitionLiveCam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Getting the list of plugged cameras
        CameraCollection cameras = vimba.Cameras;

        //Starting the chosen camera
        string id = cameras[0].Id;
        mycamera = vimba.OpenCameraByID(id, VmbAccessModeType.VmbAccessModeFull);

        // Preparing image acquisition and starting it
        Frame[] frameArray = new Frame[3];
        Feature featurePayloadSize = null;
        long payloadSize;
        featurePayloadSize = features["PayloadSize"];
        payloadSize = featurePayloadSize.IntValue;

        for (int index = 0; index < frameArray.Length; ++index)
        {
            frameArray[index] = new Frame(payloadSize);
            mycamera.AnnounceFrame(frameArray[index]);
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < frameArray.Length; ++index)
        {
            mycamera.QueueFrame(frameArray[index]);
        }

        this.m_Acquiring = true;
        mycamera.OnFrameReceived += new Camera.OnFrameReceivedHandler(this.OnFrameReceived);
        mycamera.StartContinuousImageAcquisition(1);
    }

    //Setting timer for histogram update
    Timer histTimer = new Timer();
    histTimer.Interval = 500; // specify interval time as you want
    histTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(histTimer_Tick);
    histTimer.Start();
}
```

The OnFrameReceived event is the only event that's trigered by the camera. I previously tried to make my histogram upadte on every iteration of it (by placing it's code directly in the event code), but to no avail, as I was probably limited by the computation time required.

Comment: The comment suggests to add 'some synchronization', indeed. But comments also aske about the event model you already have (beyond the Timer) and this is where the syn'ching would have to happen. What event do get triggered by the camera? Can you know when an image is ready?

Comment: @TaW I just added a more detailled version of the code that starts the acquisition from the camera. There is only one event trigered by the camera, but I am not really sure that I have a way to know when an image is ready. I will look right now in the Vimba API manual if I find womething, but is is quite cryptic and I am far from being "fluent" in C#.